# What is the exact maximum height oak trees can grow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to grow oak trees just as high as they can get - including the leaves.
And i want to build a roof on top of my tree farm.
I did not think it would be that hard to find out the maximum height of ordinary oak trees on the internet, but it kinda is.

The only hint I could find is from [the minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree):

> Large oak trees are more uncommon, and have a distinct look and
> different growth requirements. They often have "branches", outgrowths
> of wood on the sides of the trunk, or even freestanding and surrounded
> by leaves. They require 4–14 blocks of open space directly above the
> sapling to grow (air or leaves only) but can otherwise be completely
> enclosed on all sides.

But wiki just tells that large oak trees require *up to 14 blocks of open space above the sapling to grow*.
so I could guess the max height is 15 - but does this include leaves?
so maybe it's 16 for 1 or 17 for 2 additional leaf-blocks?

Does anyone know the exact height they can grow (without and with leaves)?

Comment: If there isn't the available space, it simply won't grow to that height–it can't displace another block like that (usually, though a famous glitch that used dark oak trees used to be a way to get onto the roof of the nether, though I believe that's since been patched.) Still, the question is valid.

Comment: @JMY1000 yes, but I want them to fully grow.

Comment: That's fine, but for the purpose of a tree farm, that's not what you want, as the large oaks generate randomly and are difficult to chop down and farm. You'd be better off lowering the roof to constrict it to small oak trees. Your question is still valid though.

Comment: @JMY1000 I want them to fully grow because I am using "Steve's Carts 2" to farm them in the "Feed The Beast - Infinity Evolved - Skyblock" mod-pack ;) And, apart from that, I just wanna know it as well.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 15 blocks (with leaves)

I tested this on 320 "big" trees, and got 15 blocks 2 times, never got more. I also tested if there would be some bug - eg. putting saplings in a 8x8 square, and always got a maximum height of (15 or less).

Comment: @northkildonan thanks for giving me a reason why to get more wood in my survival world :D

Comment: no problem :) is this height of 15 with or without leaves? (I'd guess without)